# Filling an array, A$(X,X) in Commodore BASIC?

Tags: arrays, printing, basic, commodore

I am trying to fill A$(X,X) with "."s in Commodore BASIC.

This is what I have so far....but I'm not really sure what to do concerning ASCII values and such. Any commentary?

```
INPUT A$
FOR I = 0 TO X = DIM A$(X,X)
A$(".",x)
```

I'm still EXTREMELY confused on PET BASIC's API... Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answers are based around a youth in front of a Commodore 64 and may not be completely correct for the PET series. But seeing as you haven't had any other answers yet I'll give it a bash.

In the first line of your code you are requesting a string from the user and storing it in `A$`. The dollar sign denotes the variable is a string. In the second line, you are redefining `A$` as a two dimensional array. The dimensions are both `X` which hasn't been defined. I don't recall `DIM` having a return value but I could be wrong.

The function to get an ASCII value from a char is `ASC()` and to convert back you use `CHR$()` such:

```
10 NUMA = ASC("A"): REM NUMA now contains 65
20 CHARA$ = CHR$(NUMA): REM CHARA$ now contains "A"
```

Something you should know is that these functions use "PET ASCII" which is slightly different to ASCII. It never caused me any problems but its something to remember.

`FOR` loops always have a `NEXT` to end the block such:

```
10 FOR A = 1 TO 10
20 PRINT A: REM Displays series of numbers.
30 NEXT
```

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve but hopefully I have at least given you enough pieces to work it out. From what I understand, you need something like:

```
10 INPUT "Please enter a number:", X
20 DIM A$(X, X)
30 FOR I = 0 TO X
40 FOR J = 0 TO X
50 A$(I, J) = "."
60 NEXT
70 NEXT
```

Comment: There is no redefining of `A$`. It is perfectly legal to have a scalar string variable `A$` and a string array `A$()` at the same time.  You can even have `A`, `A%`, `A()`, and `A%()` in addition to that.